# A good way to automatically backup a flash drive on Mac?

Tags: mac, backup, hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I have an 8GB flash drive that I would like to back up to a hard drive.  My current plan is to use a Folder Action Script to automatically run "rdiff-backup FlashDriveDirectory BackupDirectory".  Does anyone know what happens if the flash drive is disconnected while rdiff-backup is running? Will the backup directory be corrupted?  Since this is an 8GB drive, there may not always be time to run the backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answered at Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6663/what-happens-if-rsnapshot-rdiff-backup-gets-interrupted-in-the-middle-of-a-tran)